# JavaScript Regex to Replace values in given Query String

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the values of "oid" or  string "oid=1" with new string

e.g. "oid=2" in given query string using javascript and regex.

Help will be highly appreciated.

> abc.com?data=ss=AE000039&s=2014/05/07&d=2014/05/31&oid=1&th=y

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex?

Comment: regex to replace the complete oid=1 string with new string oid=2. To make regex like this oid=(any value)&. Hope this does make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend looking for a library for parsing query strings, but this should do in a pinch.

```
function updateQueryParameter(queryString, key, value) {
    return queryString.replace(new RegExp('(' + key + ')(?:=[^&]*)?'), '$1=' + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like :

```
var uri = "abc.com?data=ss=AE000039&s=2014/05/07&d=2014/05/31&oid=1&th=y";
var uri2 = uri.replace(/oid=[0-9]*/g, "oid=2");
```

Or :

```
var uri = "abc.com?data=ss=AE000039&s=2014/05/07&d=2014/05/31&oid=1&th=y";
var uri2 = uri.replace(/(oid=)[0-9]*/g, "$12");
```